# Show which events are bound it an item?

Tags: jquery, debugging, jquery-events

I remember there use to be a site that if you loaded up over your own site it would should all the jQuery bound events that existed on each item.

Does anyone know if this site still exists? Or if something better has come out can you point me to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event) that does that for all events/libraries (not just jQuery) and works in every browser. Otherwise you can use the Firefox extension [FireQuery](http://firequery.binaryage.com/) that plugs into Firebug to add jQuery-specific debug info to the DOM tab.

Comment: Visual Event is what I was looking for! I am also trying out FireQuery